# Insert Custom Field Value

Tags: post-meta, wp-insert-post

I want to insert custom post type with it's custom fields values
I have found this method to insert custom post type but with no custom fields

```php
wp_insert_post( array $postarr, bool $wp_error = false, bool $fire_after_hooks = true )
```

But the problem is on how to insert custom field values (that exists)

Comment: Did you try the `meta_input` option that's covered in the documentation? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ There's an example in the user contributed notes: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#comment-1710

Comment: Custom fields are just the name in the UI WordPress gives to post meta, all the internal functions classes tables and APIs call it meta/post meta, not custom fields

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie , that works , please put it in an answer so I can upvote it